# Rotation of a triangle.

Tags: matrices

I created a program that generates a triangle in 3d space from a matrix containing
its vertices:
For example if i use this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &1 \\ 
1 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}

I will get the following triangle (x y z):
[image]

I'd like to generate the opposite triangle:
[image]
and this matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &1 \\ 
0 &0  &1 \\ 
1 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}
I tried to keep the 2-3 rows locked and to increase the x and z of the initial matrix by 1, but I don't think it's a good solution, also because if I don't put the vertex 90 degrees on the first row it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you define "the opposite triangle"? There are three ways to rotate a triangle around an edge, because it has three edges. Would you be satisfied by saying that you want to rotate it around the edge formed by the second ad third vertex?

Comment: @Crostul Yes, i want to keep fixed the second and third vertex and rotate the first one by 180' degree

Comment: Writing the equation of a rotation around a line is not hard, however it's boring. I give you just a hint: call $V'(x',y',z')$ the coordinates of the rotated vertex, and call $V_i (x_1, y_1, z_i)$ the three vertices $(i=1,2,3)$. Then you want that: $V_1V'$ is perpendicular to $V_2V_3$ (giving you two linear equations), and you want that the midpoint of $V_1V'$ is collinear with $V_2,V_3$ (giving you the third linear equation). Solve the linear system in three equations and three unknowns and you are done.